# Javascript - Regular expression for getting a number inside a alphanumerical string?

Tags: javascript, regex

so I am looking to get an specific numerical value using Javascript and regular expressions from a string like this: *#13**67*value##

So from

```
*#13**67*2##
*#13**67*124##
*#13**67*1##
```

I need to get 2, 124 and 1. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It would help motivate potential posters if you shared what you have tried so far

Comment: Is that one mulit–line string, or 3 separate strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your strings are always in this format, match the digits at the end of the string.

```
var r = '*#13**67*124##'.match(/\d+(?=#+$)/);
if (r)
    console.log(r[0]); // => "124"
```

Multi-line matching:

```
var s = '*#13**67*2##\n*#13**67*124##\n*#13**67*1##',
    r = s.match(/\d+(?=#+$)/gm)

console.log(r); // => [ '2', '124', '1' ]
```

Perhaps `split`ting the string?

```
var r = '*#13**67*124##'.split(/[*#]+/).filter(Boolean).pop()
console.log(r); // => "124"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function getValue(string) {
    return parseInt(string.replace(/^.*(\d+)##$/gi, "$1"), 10);
}
```

Comment: The *i* flag is redundant, and why *parseInt*?

Comment: `parseInt()` returns it as a number, which may or may not be required, and yes, the `i` flag is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice example for use **regex lookahead**.

You can use this regex:

```
\d+(?=##)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/uK4rX9/1)**

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var regex = /^\*\#\d{2}\*{2}\d{2}\*(\d+)\#{2}$/;
var value = '*#13**67*124##'.match(regex)[1]; // value will be 124
```